# Carrying out a c++ 2d array

Tags: c++, 2d

My array is supposed to accept 3 values for 3 salespersons, store and print the array but somehow I can't get it going. I'm not too familiar with c++ 2d arrays so this is a tad bit new to me. The code is supposed to accept user input, and then output the prices of the products into table like format.

Comment: Please format your code. The current format is difficult to read, especially `}}}}` and `for(j=3;j<2;j++)
    {
   }` are strange.

Comment: Instead of sprinkling `2`, `3` and other numbers throughout your code, define `const int salesPersonCount = 2` or something like that so we know what you're talking about. For example, your second level arrays have 7 entries for absolutely no apparent reason.

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Do you get error messages? Is the output wrong?

Comment: ⟼Remember, it's always important, *especially* when learning and asking questions on Stack Overflow, to keep your code as organized as possible. [Consistent indentation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indentation_style) helps communicate structure and, importantly, intent, which helps us navigate quickly to the root of the problem without spending a lot of time trying to decode what's going on.

Comment: Try and get out of the habit of `using namespace std`. That prefix is there for a reason: To protect you from naming collisions and to make it clear where those functions, data structures and other things come from.

Answer (score 1):

I had to clean up *a lot* of code to get this to even begin to compile. There were many cases where the closing `}` of a block was not present. These mistakes are easy to make, but they're also easy to spot if you're *disciplined about maintaining a consistent indentation style*.

Once I indented the code it became fairly obvious where the errors were, but identifying these in the original is very hard.

Here's the cleaned up code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

int main( ) {
  const int salesPersonCount =3, productCount = 3;

  int rows = 5, columns = 5;
  int sales[rows][columns];
  double total;

  for (int p = 1; p <= salesPersonCount; p++) {
    std::cout << "\n \n Information for SalesPsn"<< p <<" : \n \n";

    //Sales Person
    for (int m = 1; m <=productCount; m++) {
      //Product Number
      std::cout << "\n Please enter sales value of product "<< m << ":";

      std::cout << "\n ";

      for (int i=0;i<rows;i++) {
        for (int j=3;j<columns; j++) {
          std::cout << "\nThe 2-D Array is:\n";

          for (int i=0;i<2;i++) {
            for (int j=0;j<2;j++) {
              std::cout << "\t" << sales[i][j];
            }

            std::cout << "Sale " << std::setw (17) << "Salespsn1" << std::setw (22)<< "Salespsn2" 
              << std::setw (27)<< "Salespsn3" << std::setw (32) << "Total" << std::endl;
          }

          std::cout << std::endl;
        }
      }
    }
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Note this still has a *lot* of problems you're going to need to resolve, like how you're capturing sales and information into variables `p` and `m` which are *also* used for iterators, plus how nothing actually puts data into the `sales` structure, but at least you've got something you can fix.

My advice: When you get into a deep hole, stop digging. If you can't figure out what to do, clean up your code. I've solved many problems in the course of better organizing what I've done, in adding comments to parts that should work yet don't. There's no shame in being stuck, but if you're stuck because of a mess you didn't clean up that's on you.

Comment: In some cases, it might be worth digging a new hole. It's all but impossible for a newbie to debug code with multiple issues, because fixing one issue doesn't necessarily result in any visible progress as all the other issues remain. So sometimes it's better to start again. Lessons will have been learned from the previous attempt. Hopefully you'll go a bit slower this time, so you are only facing one problem at a time.

Comment: @john Fully agree. That's why learning how to use a version control system as a developer is critical. You can always go back to an older version if your experiment fails, or you can try different approaches in different branches.

Answer (score 0):

I went over the code and this is the final product... Turns out no input was needed I was overthinking. Thanks for the help @tadman For anyone who is interested:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#define ROW 3 //number of rows
#define COL 3 // number of columns

//Function Prototype section
    void enterItems(double salesArray[][COL]);
    void getRowTotal (double Sales[][3], double total[][3]);
    void getColTotal (double Sales[][3], double total[][3]);
    void DisplayArray (double Sales[][3], double total[][3]);

using namespace std;


int main (){ //function main begins program execution

    //storing 3 sales person and 3 different product

//Declares Arrays

 double Sales[ROW][COL] = { {250,200,300 }, {500,350,220 },{150,600,450 }};
 double total[2][3] = {0};

//Calls Functions getRowTotal, getColTotal and DisplayArray
getRowTotal (Sales, total);
getColTotal(Sales, total);
DisplayArray (Sales, total);

//Signifies that program is successfully executed
return 0;

}



//variables
int z = 0, j = 0;


//Declares And Defines getRowTotal
void getRowTotal (double Sales[][3], double total[][3]){
for(z = 0; z < 3; z++)
total[0][z] = Sales[0][z] + Sales[1][z] + Sales[2][z];
}

//Declares and Defines getColTotal
void getColTotal(double Sales[][3], double total[][3]){

for(z = 0; z < 3; z++){
total[1][z] = Sales[z][0] + Sales[z][1] + Sales[z][2];
}
}

//function DisplayArry
void DisplayArray (double Sales[][3], double total[][3]){
//Table Headings
cout << left << setw(10) << "Title" << setw(15) << "SalesPerson1    " << setw(15) << "SalesPerson2      " << setw(15) << "SalesPerson3      " << "Total";
cout << "\n_______________________________________________________________________________________________\n";

cout << fixed << setprecision(2) << showpoint;

//Displays the Sales and row headings
for(z = 0; z < 3; z++){
cout << setw(8) << "Product  " << z + 1 << setw(1) << " ";

for(j = 0; j < 3; j++)
cout << setw(17) << Sales[j][z];

cout << setw(17) << total[0][z];

cout << endl;
}

cout << setw(8) << "Total";

for( z = 0; z < 3; z++)
cout << setw(19) << total[1][z];

cout << "\n_______________________________________________________________________________________________\n";
}
```